# Not able to scrape links in python with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape all the links on a webpage which is tag  and class="author track". There are multiple URLs like this on a web page but when i run the program, my list is empty

Example of one HTML:-

```
<a class="author track" href="/nileshkikuuchise" data-gaq="author" data-dmc="entry-artist">
                                                                        <img class="avatar" src="https://ctl.s6img.com/cdn/s6-original-art-uploads/society6/uploads/u/nileshkikuuchise/avatar_asset/5323d6c4d92143e8b37f0fa644d7044f_p3.jpg" width="20" height="20" data-dmc="entry-photo">
                                                                    Nileshkikuuchise                                </a>
```

My code:-

```
discover_page = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
finding_accounts = discover_page.find_all("a", "[class~=author track]")
print(finding_accounts)
```

and output is none

How do i get the href value to the list?. I can do the for loop later but need to get the basics correct first

Comment: Did you try `discover_page.find_all("a", class_="author track")`? The `~` looks a bit weird there. `discover_page.select('a[class="author track"]')` should also work.

Comment: I think the error is just `class` should be `class_`

Comment: I tried all the above but didnt work? Maybe the problem is that it can find element but not able to print it in console.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a mix of the style expected by `select` and by `find_all`.

These two methods work for me:

```
>>> r = '''
<a class="author track" href="/nileshkikuuchise" data-gaq="author" data-dmc="entry-artist">
                                                                        <img class="avatar" src="https://ctl.s6img.com/cdn/s6-original-art-uploads/society6/uploads/u/nileshkikuuchise/avatar_asset/5323d6c4d92143e8b37f0fa644d7044f_p3.jpg" width="20" height="20" data-dmc="entry-photo">
                                                                    Nileshkikuuchise                                </a>
'''

>>> discover_page = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
>>> discover_page.find_all("a", class_="author track")
[<a class="author track" data-dmc="entry-artist" data-gaq="author" href="/nileshkikuuchise">
 <img class="avatar" data-dmc="entry-photo" height="20" src="https://ctl.s6img.com/cdn/s6-original-art-uploads/society6/uploads/u/nileshkikuuchise/avatar_asset/5323d6c4d92143e8b37f0fa644d7044f_p3.jpg" width="20"/>
                                                                     Nileshkikuuchise                                </a>]
>>> discover_page.select('a[class="author track"]')
[<a class="author track" data-dmc="entry-artist" data-gaq="author" href="/nileshkikuuchise">
 <img class="avatar" data-dmc="entry-photo" height="20" src="https://ctl.s6img.com/cdn/s6-original-art-uploads/society6/uploads/u/nileshkikuuchise/avatar_asset/5323d6c4d92143e8b37f0fa644d7044f_p3.jpg" width="20"/>
                                                                     Nileshkikuuchise                                </a>]
```

Comment: it worked for me also, maybe the problem is in logging. How do i print href value from html to console?

Comment: @SultanMorbiwala: Note that both of my versions are different from yours. Running your code does indeed produce an empty list. You can get the links by iterating over the list: `print([a["href"] for a in discover_page.select('a[class="author track"]')])`